# mysqli database connection already declared, still receive error: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How `$con` is declared (line 7 of the script):

```
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$mysql_user,$mysql_pw,$dbname);
```

The code causing the error:

```
$question = "INSERT INTO `" . $pollid . "` (id, q, yesno) VALUES (NULL, '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $q) . "', '" . $yesno . "')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $question)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
Error:
```

`$con` is used elsewhere in the script and works absolutely fine. The credentials are correct. When it comes to this part of the script it starts giving me the following:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in *.php on line 133

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in *.php on line 135

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in *.php on line 136
```

I've looked for a solution elsewhere and have been fruitless.

Comment: What does it show when you `var_dump($con)`? If it's null something is going wrong there.

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to be sure, but you might have a scope issue - that is, you've declared `$con` somewhere and tried to use it in a function where it's no longer visible. Or viceversa.

Comment: Bono, it shows NULL.

EDIT: I understand the issue now, thanks for the help. It is, as you suggested, a scope issue.